# Chrome running out of memory

Tags: google-chrome, memory, google-chrome-extension

I've developed a Chrome Extension that cycles through approximately 1500-2000 pages to collect information from a website and push it onto my own server. I use a Chrome extension, as given the requirements it's much easier to configure than making and parsing from the server side.

The extension is used only for internal purposes and we trigger this job using the [chrome.alarm API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms.html) to run at 3:00 am every day. This alarm when triggers pops open a new tab and runs through the 1500-2000 pages. The problem is when we check in the morning we see the [SNAP dialogue](http://www.brianjeremy.com/_media/google_snap.gif) after the extension has cycled through about 1500 pages (approx 3/4). I'm presuming this is due to the memory demand placed on Chrome to maintain such an unusually large history?

My question is, what would be the best way to mitigate this? Presumably killing the tab and reopening (after x number of pages) would work but that would slow down the feed and require quite a bit of code re-factoring. Is there any way you can force Chrome to dump the history and would doing so free memory in the immediate session?

Just to add some context, I am running this on a extra small VM with only 1 GB of memory. I appreciate I could upgrade the VM but that really just defers the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to make a solid recommendation without seeing your code, but here's something a bit more general:

The problem is likely the information that is being collected. It continues to build up in memory until you run out. You might consider saving the results to local storage using Chrome's unlimited storage capability. In manifest file:

```
 "permissions": [
   "unlimitedStorage"
 ],
```

What I would probably do is save to local storage after every page, or something similar, and then reset the array (or whatever you're using).

*UPDATE*

If indeed history is the problem, you could consider deleting it on the fly. This function will delete entries for a specific URL:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history.html#method-deleteUrl

Comment: On each page cycle I'm using just 8 localStorage variables that get overwritten each time. The variables are storing very short name value key pairs, so the memory footprint here will be very small. I'm pretty certain that it's the accumulated history that's an issue. Imagine pressing the back button 1500 times to pull each historic page from memory. I think I'm gonna reconfigure the extension to open a new tab and close the old one every nth page. Thanks for pointing out unlimitedStorage, that's a new one on me!

Comment: In the end I recycled the tab on every 5th page, no more Snap messages. Incidentally when I log `history.length` after every page cycle it only reaches a max of 50. I know it's storing more in memory however as I can see the memory deplete as more and more pages are cycled.